# Entity Framework 4.0. How to create new property like Compute Column on SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to create a new column, based on another property. The new Property must be on a different datatype. I need to use the new property to create a association to another object.
The new property must be Int32.

I need something like `cast(stringField as int)` on SQL.

I know that I can use a partial class to create the new property, but i need to create a new Association.

Comment: Why would you need such a thing? What is your class for? An example would clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties using a partial class

```
public partial class YourClass
{
    public int YourProperty
    {
        get { return int.Parse(this.aStringValue); }
    }
}
```

Can give more detail by what you mean with assosiation or why the partial class implementation will not work for you.